# How to find the range of $\tanh x$ using epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the range of $\tanh x$ by using epsilon-delta.

I have shown that $\tanh x$ is an odd function, which I can use to split my proof into two parts. One for $x\in[0,\infty)$ and one for $x\in(-\infty,0]$.

What I am now trying to do is to use epsilon-delta, to proof for $x\in [0,\infty)$ (part one), but i'm stuck at the following.

$$\text{hypothesis: }\tanh x\rightarrow 1, x\rightarrow\infty$$

$$\left|\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

How do I proceed from here? Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}\left\lvert\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}-1\right\rvert&=1-\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\\&=\frac{2e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\\&<2e^{-2x}.\end{align}Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-2x}=0$, there is a $M>0$ such that$$x>M\implies e^{-2x}<\frac\varepsilon2$$and therefore$$x>M\implies2e^{-2x}<\varepsilon.$$So,$$x>M\implies\left\lvert\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Hey. Is the value of $M$ equal to $2e^{-2x}$?

Comment: @mathstudent23 No. And that doesn't make sense. The number $M$ cannot depend upon $x$.

Comment: Ah so with $\epsilon$ instead of $x$? I was explained you have to explicitly assign an expression to $M$ as that is the point of the scratch work?

Comment: You can take $M=-\frac{\log(\varepsilon/2)}2$.